# How to unlink a npm command-line tool?

Tags: node.js, npm

I use node to write a command-line tool.

this is the index.js.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('qiuyuntao');
```

this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "qiu",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bin": {
    "qyt": "index.js"
  }
}
```

After I use command `npm link`, I can use command `qyt` anywhere. Now I want to unlink the `command`, I use `npm unlink`, it said

```
npm ERR! gentlyRm containing path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/qiu isn't under npm's control
npm WARN install:qiu@1.0.0 Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/qyt not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/qiu
- qiu@1.0.0 node_modules/qiu
```

So, what should I do to unlink it?

Comment: What version of `npm` do you have installed?

Comment: my `npm` version is `3.3.12`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what version of npm you are using and if this is a bug thats being resolved I suspect that your global prefix is misconfigured perhaps.

At any rate the easiest solution is to manually remove the symlinks `/usr/local/bin/qyt` and `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/qiu`. If you are using the latest version of npm look into filing an issue, otherwise update (`npm i -g npm`).

Comment: After delete `/usr/local/bin/qyt` and `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/qiu`, I can still use command `qyt`. It does't echo `qiuyuntao `, but echo `Empty string`.

Comment: Not really sure whats going on there but using the shell command `type qyt` will either give you the location of the executable or tell you if its a shell function etc

Answer (score 0):

Updating npm `3.9.5` > `4.0.5` fixed the same issue for me

Before update:

```
$ npm unlink
npm WARN install:@coolman/my-module@1.0.0 Refusing to delete /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/mymod: ../lib/node_modules/my-module/index-cli.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/@coolman/my-module
- @coolman/my-module@1.0.0 node_modules/@coolman/my-module

$ npm --version
3.9.5
```

After update:

```
$ sudo npm install npm@latest -g

$ npm --version
4.0.5

$ npm unlink
- @coolman/my-module@1.0.0 node_modules/@coolman/my-module
```

And to repeat `npm link`, I needed to manually remove the bin:

```
$ npm link
npm WARN @my-company/my-module@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/npm" "link"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! path /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/mymod
npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/mymod: ../lib/node_modules/my-module/index-cli.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /Users/coolman/my-company/tools/my-module
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/mymod
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/coolman/my-company/tools/my-module/npm-debug.log


$ rm /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/mymod

$ npm link
npm WARN @coolman/my-module@1.0.0 No repository field.
/Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/bin/mymod -> /Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/@coolman/my-module/index-cli.js
/Users/coolman/.nvm/versions/node/v6.2.0/lib/node_modules/@coolman/my-module -> /Users/coolman/perkbox/tools/run-with-pb-session
```